# NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to get url string from NSString. I do the following:

```
   NSString * str = [NSString stringWithString:@"i@gmail.com"];

    NSString * eStr = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",eStr);
```

The result is i@gmail.com. But I need i%40gmail.com. replacing NSUTF8StringEncoding with NSASCIIStringEncoding doesn't help.

Comment: did you figure out how to replace stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. This does the opposite, translating percent
escapes to their characters. You probably want to use
`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

```
NSString *str  = @"i@gmail.com";
NSString *eStr =
    [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

Apart from that, looks like the `@` character is not escaped by default. Then,
as the documentation for the above method points out, you'll need to use
CoreFoundation to achieve what you want.

```
NSString *str  = @"i@gmail.com";

CFStringRef eStr = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    (CFStringRef)str,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"@",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8
);

NSLog(@"%@", eStr);

CFRelease(eStr);
```

Please check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes) to know more about the function used and
how to make it fit your needs.